# Create a new column named Group_ID groups based on First few characters of the First Name & Last Name

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a data like with First Name & Last Name

```
First_Name                Last_Name
Neetu                     Puri
Puri                      Neetu
Sheena                    Arora
Reena                     Arora
Arora                     Sheena
```

No I want create a new column named Block_ID. The records which have First two characters of First_Name and First two characters of Last_Name or First two characters of Last_Name and First two characters of First_Name, they must fall in the same Block.

Following is the output I am looking for:

```
First_Name                Last_Name        Block_ID
Neetu                     Puri              1
Puri                      Neetu             1
Sheena                    Arora             2
Reena                     Arora             3
Arora                     Sheena            2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can slice the first 2 characters, [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) the two columns as [`frozenset`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset)s and [`factorize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html):

```
df['Block_ID'] = pd.factorize(list(map(frozenset,
                                       zip(df['First_Name'].str[:2],
                                           df['Last_Name'].str[:2]))))[0]+1
```

Output:

```
  First_Name Last_Name  Block_ID
0      Neetu      Puri         1
1       Puri     Neetu         1
2     Sheena     Arora         2
3      Reena     Arora         3
4      Arora    Sheena         2
```

Intermediate frozensets before the `factorize` step:

```
[frozenset({'Ne', 'Pu'}),
 frozenset({'Ne', 'Pu'}),
 frozenset({'Ar', 'Sh'}),
 frozenset({'Ar', 'Re'}),
 frozenset({'Ar', 'Sh'})]
```

Alternatively, using [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) (but with a different order):

```
group = np.unique(np.sort(list(zip(df['First_Name'].str[:2],
                                   df['Last_Name'].str[:2]))),
                  axis=0, return_inverse=True)[1]
# array([2, 2, 1, 0, 1])
```